# In-place modification from Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I would like to run a geometry processing algorithm from the Python console while using the *Edit features in-place* modifier.

I copied the output from the processing history to see if it works, e.g:

```
processing.run("native:rotatefeatures", {'INPUT':'/path/to/layer.shp','ANGLE':40,'ANCHOR':None,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```

but wasn't surprised that it didn't.
So what's the trick? (if there is one)

I'm on QGIS 3.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no direct API for doing this. But the following works

```
from processing.gui import AlgorithmExecutor
rotatealg = QgsApplication.processingRegistry().createAlgorithmById('native:rotatefeatures')
layer = iface.activeLayer()
AlgorithmExecutor.execute_in_place(rotatealg, {'ANGLE':40, 'ANCHOR':None, 'INPUT': layer})
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug in your snipped: 'native:roatefeatures' should be 'native:rotatefeatures' (with 't').