# Run processing algorithm in-place to modify INPUT layer via PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a line layer with lines potentially having multiple vertices (aside from start and end point) and I need the concerned features to be split at the vertex.

The `explodelines` algorithm does this but it creates a new layer. **I need imperatively to edit my input layer as opposed to create a new one.** I can't also create a new .shp layer and work with that one instead since I need to run a bunch of operations on it.

So far I've found these two threads [Building a QGIS 3.10 script without an output layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362500/building-a-qgis-3-10-script-without-an-output-layer) and [Modify the input layer when using processing algorithms from the console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231843/modify-the-input-layer-when-using-processing-algorithms-from-the-console) but I can't find a solution in neither.

If there's somehow a way to directly edit input layer directly using processing algorithms that would be the best case scenario as a lot of operations are covered by readily available algorithms already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run Processing algorithms to edit input features in-place (that is, to modify the `INPUT` layer instead of modifying a copy) in this way:

```
from processing.gui.AlgorithmExecutor import execute_in_place

# Get algorithm instance
registry = QgsApplication.instance().processingRegistry()
alg = registry.algorithmById("native:explodelines")

# Run the algorithm using 'in-place' edits
line_layer = iface.activeLayer()
params = {'INPUT': line_layer}
execute_in_place(alg, params)
```

---

Notes:

- It is not required that your `INPUT` layer is the current active layer. Just pass a reference to a layer and you're done.
- Make sure you don't have any feature selection on your input layer before running the algorithm. Otherwise, changes will only be applied to selected features.
- After the algorithm execution, your layer will be in edit mode waiting for you to save changes (just like when you run it from the GUI). As you're using a script, it makes sense to save changes also automatically. For that, just write `line_layer.commitChanges()` at the end.
- The `native:explodelines` only expects the `INPUT/OUTPUT` layer parameters. For other algorithms, you'd pass the whole set of parameters (see [how to get parameters of a specific algorithm](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276976/what-is-the-new-alglist-and-alghelp-in-qgis-3-0-processing/276979#276979)).
- There is no need of passing the `OUTPUT` parameter to run an algorithm in-place, but if you pass it, the algorithm will still work in-place mode.
- It may be useful to check if an algorithm can be run in-place on a specific layer, before running it. For that, you can use `alg.supportInPlaceEdit(line_layer)`, which returns a boolean result.

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick. I ended up finding this thread while looking around https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327858/in-place-modification-from-python looking around but your explanation will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the processing scripts you can use "in place" just press the inplace button. Explode lines is one of them. There will no new layer  produced.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I can get snap geometries to layer https://i.stack.imgur.com/scfP6.png but I don't get it for explode lines https://i.stack.imgur.com/vURTF.png

Also, would there a way to do it through a python script as opposed to running it from the processing toolbox ?

Comment: While running the snap geometries to layer algorithm while "Edit features in palce" enabled, the "source layer" argument is missing, so I can only the reference layer so I can't pick the point layer which it should snap to. @eurojam

Comment: you have to select the layer before searching explode, if your active layer will be a pointlayer, there will no explode

Comment: Great @eurojam - did not know about this possibility!